# Calculating the entropy of a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, information-theory

I am looking to calculate the information contained in a neural network. I am also looking to calculate the maximum information contained by any neural network in a certain amount of bits. These two measures should be comparable (as in I can compare whether my current neural network has reached the max or is less than the max and by how much).

Information is relative, so I define it relative to the real a priori distribution of the data that the neural network is trying to estimate.

I have come across Von Neumann entropy which can be applied to a matrix, but because it is not additive I can't apply it to a series of weight matrices (assuming the weight matrices encode all the information of a neural network).

I found three other papers [Entropy-Constrained raining of Deep Neural Networks](http://iphome.hhi.de/samek/pdf/WieIJCNN19.pdf) , [Entropy and mutual information in models of deep neural networks](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7453-entropy-and-mutual-information-in-models-of-deep-neural-networks.pdf) and [Deep Learning and the Information Bottleneck Principle](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02406.pdf). The second contains a link to  [this](https://github.com/sphinxteam/dnner) github repo, but this method requires the activation functions and weight matrices to be known which is not the case for finding the max entropy of any neural network in n bits.

How can I calculate the amount of information contain in/entropy of a neural network? And how can I calculate the same measure for any neural network in n bits?

Comment: Welcome to DS SE! Currently, this post is a series of statements. Would you please update it by asking a question?

Comment: @BenjiAlbert done

Comment: Great (neat topic btw! +1). hopefully someone can answer you

Comment: My information theory is quite rusty.  Is it actually possible to compute the entropy of a function (the neural network) relative to a distribution (the data)?

Comment: @zachdj I don't think you can calculate the entropy of a function, but you can calculate the entropy of a distribution, so think about it instead as calculating the entropy of the posterior distribution of the data generated by that function maybe? I'm rusty on it as well.

Answer (score 1):

To start, see *Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms* by David J.C. MacKay, starting with chapter 40 for information capacity of a single neuron (two bits per weight) through to at least chapter 42 for Hopfield Networks (fully connected feedback). The classic reference for information of a Hopfield Network is *Information Capacity of the Hopfield Model* by Abu-Mostafa & St. Jacques, but the textbook should have enough.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. Is there a specific calculation you can cite that is most relevant to the question?